# Is there any way to pin more than 6 items to the quickplay screen in Zuneware?

Tags: zune-software, pin, high-resolution

I use the Zune software for my media playing on my laptop, and it lets you pin things (albums, artists, playlists, etc.) to the homescreen for quick access to your favorite items.

Stupid thing though is that it only lets you pin 6 items... after which is starts to drop off older items when you pin a new one. Back in the day this might have made sense, but on a screen running at a resolution of 1920 x 1200, it makes absolutely NO sense, and leads to an IMMENSE waste of space.

Anyone know of a hack, registry edit or other way to get the Zuneware to pin more than 6 items?